# Is there anyway that I can send the link of my question to someone requesting the answer in SE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions

At the end of the question there is an option like

> Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email,
>   Google+, Twitter, or Facebook.

But I could not find an option to contact somebody in tex.stackexchange itself.

Is there anyway that I can send the link of my question to someone requesting the answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By-design, StackExchange does not have any feature of direct user-to-user communication.* The aim of the network is to build up knowledge/Q&A with general scope, which is almost always the opposite of what user-to-user communication would be for.

*The one exception is that moderators can directly contact users, but this is for serious moderation issues only.